# check character and converting emoticon to text? c#

Tags: c#, replace, emoticons

I have list of emoticon in database like this

```
id | emoticon | convert_text

1  |   :)     |  e_happy

2  |   :(     |  e_sad
```

etc.

How to check if there are any characters included in the list of emoticons?

If found, then change emoticon into text.

Example:

```
before
S = Smile at everyone who doesn't smile at your :)

after
S= Smile at everyone who doesn't smile at your e_happy
```

*Edited

First I've tried to split every word like this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string value = "Smile at everyone who doesn't smile at your :)";
        char[] delimiter = new char[] { ' ', ',', '.' };

        string[] array = value.Split(delimiter, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (string entry in array)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(entry);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

I am confused how to check each word with a list of emoticons in the database and convert emoticon to text like in example
*Sorry this is my first post and I'm translating with google translate

Comment: So the first part is getting a map of emoticons to the corresponding convert_text token from the database. That depends on what database you're using. Do you already have this part done?

Comment: You can store the `emoticon` and `convert_text` into a `Dictionary<string,string>` where key is `emoticon` is the key and `convert_text` is the value. Then user the dictionary to find and replace the words.

Once problem you may run into will be that you split characters might be lost and you may have to figure out a way for it

Answer (score 1):

As the number and symbols of the emoticons can be very large and very random (*`like :) ;) >:) @}-, etc; and then new can be added anytime`*) I think Regular expressions cannot be used for all of them. So I would like to approach this problem in a more verbose way.

1. Load all the emoticons in a dictionary containing the emoticon as key and convert_text as value (just make sure that the key is not repeated, otherwise there will be an exception)
2. Do a foreach for each emoticon key and replace it in the text

**Declaring the Dictionary**

```
Dictionary<string, string> emoticons = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

**Loading emoticons into the dictionary (using DataReader)**

```
// declare/open the connection (depends on the current application design

string sql = "SELECT * FROM Emoticons
// cmd.ExecuteReader above query to get dataReader (dr)

while(dr.Read())
{
    string key = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("Emoticons"));

    if(!emoticons.ContainsKey(key))
        emoticons.Add(key, dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("convert_test"));
}
dr.Close();
```

*The above dictionary can be stored as a class level object or as a project level global object so that you do not need to read the database every time.*

**Replacing all emoticons with convert_text**

```
foreach(string key in emoticons.Keys)
   value = value.Replace(key, emoticons[key]);

// here you will have all emoticons converted with their convert_text.
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using regular expressions?

```
var emoticons = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { ":)" , "smile" },
    { ";)" , "blink" },
    { ">:)", "devil" },
    { "@}-", "rose"  }
};
string value = "Smile at everyone who doesn't smile at your :)";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(value, 
    String.Join("|",emoticons.Select(e => Regex.Escape(e.Key)).ToArray()), 
    (match) =>
    {
        string result = null;
        return emoticons.TryGetValue(match.Value, out result) 
            ? result : match.Value;
    }));
```

By using regexps you can match a `:)` or `:]` by using the same expression, if you already put them correctly escaped in your database. In this sample I consider all expressions are "unsafe", so I use that `Regex.Escape` call